# How to use amplify in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, aws-amplify

I need to use amplify in flutter. 
Any idea how to do that? 
I am familiar with firebase auth
 If there is no option to implement the amplify in flutter, then is that possible to write code in firebase cloud function and ues it in flutter

Answer (score 0):

Recently the team at Amplify began working on Amplify Flutter. You can check out their repo [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter).

It is still in developer preview, so don't expect to be using It in production applications just yet.

Currently, they support [Authentication](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-apps-with-aws-backend-part-2-authentication-a66136f23995), [Analytics](https://medium.com/@vennify.education/flutter-apps-with-aws-backend-part-3-analytics-bdb8b5bad5c0), and [Storage](https://medium.com/@vennify.education/flutter-apps-with-aws-backend-part-4-storage-74ae2dbdc4b5), and they plan on adding to this feature set in the near future.

- Authentication is provided through Cognito.
- Analytics is provided through Pinpoint.
- Storage is provided through S3.

If you need help getting set up, head over to their documentation or [these articles](https://medium.com/@vennify.education/flutter-apps-with-aws-backend-part-1-basic-setup-7e1dd53e9161) which I used to help me get up and running with some basic apps: